# Passing initial value to custom input component

Tags: redux-form

I am creating a custom input to handle a toggle switch.

**Form component**

```
<Field 
    label='Link to individuals' 
    name='employeeLink' 
    value={true}
    component={Switch}
/>
```

If I log `this.props.input.value` of the Switch component I get `value: ""`. How do I pass the initial `value` as seen in the form component to the Switch? Updating the value works as expected.

Or do I need to call `componentDidMount` as below? If yes, will it not always be dirty?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.input.onChange(this.props.input.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally forgot that redux-form provides a way to pass initial values

See:

http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/initializeFromState/
http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/#-initialvalues-object-string-string-optional-